# Migrate to datomic from postgres

Tags: database, clojure, datomic

is there any way to migrate to datomic directly from postgres..?

I have one existing postgres database i am planning to migrate to datomic 
is there any source or library from where i can get help?

Answer (score 8):

There's no straight-forward answer to this question or automated, general purpose tool for this. In general, [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) is not trivial, especially when moving between different types of databases (e.g. from table-backed SQL to Datomic).

That said, to get started in solving this for your case you might find [Onyx](http://michaeldrogalis.tumblr.com/post/98378329045/onyx-a-new-data-bridge), a project that transfers data to and from a SQL database (MySQL) and Datomic, to be a helpful example.

EDIT: As of December 2016, there is now a video available demonstrating a way to architecture an import job from SQL to Datomic by Stu Halloway, available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOON--g1PyU).